# FWHM of something which does not reach half of maximum?

Tags: filter, math

There is some curve for which I have find FWHM. But the curve does not reach half maximum i.e., its maximum is 1 and it only reaches .7 (but it does have the bell curved shape the filters have). Right now I am considering half maximum as (1-.7)/2, is this correct? I am confused.

Comment: FWHM - what is it and how does this relate to EE?

Comment: Full width half maximum? Its used to find the bandwidth of filters? I am working on filter problems but the power output is not going below the half of maximum.

Comment: FWHM (Full width half maximum) is a way of measuring the width of a band pass filter. It's an uncommon measurment in EE. But in other fields like optics, this is the standard. Do you try to measure a band pass optical filter?

Comment: You got me, yes. But I thought it should follow the same math. (But I have calculated FWHM of electrical filters too, but they never had this problem)

Comment: What units are used in the quantity you are measuring?

Comment: Its a power ratio. So unit less

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the reason is why the curve doesn't drop below 0.7.

If it's because of a background input at your sensor (a common situation in optical measurements), then you should subtract off that background value, and you'll end up with the formula you proposed.

If the reason is something to do with the filter itself, then that isn't an appropriate solution. Maybe you could extrapolate curve to the half-maximum values, or maybe the concept of FWHM doesn't apply to this filter at all.

Answer (score 0):

You measure the response as a function of frequency. (or something)  You find the maximum of that curve.  You then find the two points one each side of the max that have 1/2 that amplitude.  The difference in frequency between those two half amplitude points is the width (FWHM). Sometimes people give you the half width at half maximum (HWHM).

If you want to compare to someone else's numbers you have to know if you should measure in power or amplitude. (V^2 or Volts)